# disabling prettyPhoto on mobile

Tags: mobile, modernizr, prettyphoto

I may be too much of a noob to be asking here, but I've gotten a lot of help with other issues by searching here and finding others Q&A's, so am going to try my own.

The short version of what I'm looking for is a way to disable prettyPhoto on small mobile screens (phones, not tablets) - or maybe even better to just disable the caption ("title" text) when on phones only.

Originally, I wasn't able to get prettyPhoto to open when viewed on the phone. I fixed that with this solution: (I'm not allowed to post the link since this is my first post - but the bitly address is 10tsboq)

But now the caption ("title" text in the code) forms a long vertical string as shown here: http://grab.by/j9f0

I did find this solution posted to disable prettyPhoto altogether on phones using Modernizr, http://forums.no-margin-for-errors.com/discussion/5282/pretty-photo-on-a-mobile-device-iphone#Item_7 but either I'm not understanding where to put the code or I've just done it wrong.     Anyone know where that code should go? (just tacked on at the bottom of the prettyPhoto js or css? Or replacing something existing in the code?  Or somewhere else altogether?

Or - any other completely different suggestions to solve the issue?

(by the way, I'm working on a Squarespace v6 platform for the site, in case that matters)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

for anyone looking for the answer to this, I tracked down a commenter on the original post and they were super cool about being willing to answer a strangers email to offer explanation -  so, to answer the question I had posed on the modernizr script - it goes into the prettyPhoto code that is most likely in your footer:

(something like this):

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();
INSERT MODERNIZR MQ CODE HERE
  });
</script>
```

hope that helps someone!